# (javascript) Get all object keys from array of objects with dynamic properties

Tags: javascript

What's the easiest way to get object keys from array of objects.
Ex.

```
var obj = [{"foo": 1, "bar": 2}, {"foo": 10, "bar": 20, "baz": 30}]
// ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
```

Comment: What do you want? A merged array of keys or all keys?

Comment: var obj = [{"foo": 1, "bar": 2}, {"foo": 10, "bar": 20, "baz": 30}];


var checkKeys = function () {
    var KeysArr=[];
    obj.forEach(function (item) {
        
        var keys = Object.keys(item);
        keys.forEach(function (key) {
            if(KeysArr.indexOf(key)==-1)
            {
                KeysArr.push(key);
            };
        });


    });
    return KeysArr;
};


console.log(checkKeys());

Comment: all unique, keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map everything to a single array with reduce:

```
obj.reduce((acc, curr) => acc.concact(Object.keys(curr)), [])
```

This gives you:

```
['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar', 'baz']
```

Comment: Thanks!
To remove duplicates, I did:
`data.reduce((acc, curr) => acc.concat(Object.keys(curr)), []).filter(( item, index, inputArray ) => inputArray.indexOf(item) == index)`

Comment: @HarleyDelaCruz you can also use `[...new Set(data)]` where `data` is the name of your array.